# ERROR 1064 (42000) Al dar privilegios sore algunas columnas

Tags: mysql

Estoy tratando de dar privilegios a un usuario y me está dando un error de sintáxis que no logro localizar. Es una línea de código copida que he usado anteriormente y no me ha dado problemas, solo he cambiado las columnas de las tablas.

Esta es:

> GRANT UPDATE(nombre, apellido1, apellido2, edad, curso_actual), DELETE(nombre, apellido1, apellido2, edad, curso_actual) ON instituto.alumnos TO userexterno@'%';

y el error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(nombre, apellido1, apellido2, edad, curso_actual) ON instituto.alumnos TO usere' at line 1

Si alguien puede abrirme los ojos... Gracias

Comment: ¿Las columnas que indicas se corresponden con las de la tabla `instituto.alumnos`?

Comment: Si, son de la 2ª a la 6ª respectivamente, quiedo dar privilegios de update y delete sobre todas las columnas menos la primera, que sería clave_alumnos.

Comment: Versión de MySQL que usas?

Comment: 8.0.22  Pero ayer me funcionaba, estoy probando y aparentemente el problema es el paréntesis o lo que está dentro, porque puedo usar grant o revoke sienmpre que no especifique columnas entre paréntesis)